# $\exists\ c\in \mathbb{C},\mathrm{ s.t.} \det (\mathscr{T} A)=c \cdot \det A, \forall\ A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathscr{T}$ be a linear transform of $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Show that

\begin{aligned}
\exists\ c\in \mathbb{C},\mathrm{ s.t.} \det (\mathscr{T} A)=c \cdot \det A, \forall\ A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}.
\end{aligned}

Let $\mathscr{T}E_{ij}=\sum_{k,l}t_{ijkl}E_{kl}$, where $E_{kl}$ has only $(k,l)$ entry $1$. Then
$\mathscr{T}A=\mathscr{T}(\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}E_{ij})
=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\sum_{k,l}t_{ijkl} E_{kl}$, so $(k,l)$ entry of $\mathscr{T}A$ is $tr(AT_{kl}')$, where $T_{kl}=(t_{ijkl})$. Then....

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that the conclusion is correct.

---

Take $n = 2$. Define
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{T}\colon \quad \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2} & \to \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}, \\
X & \mapsto AX + XB,
\end{align*}
$$
in which
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is not hard to check that $\mathscr{T}$ is linear.

Let
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is not hard to check that
$$
\det {(\mathscr{T}X)} =
\det {\begin{bmatrix}
b & c+d \\
a & c+d \\
\end{bmatrix}} = (b-a)(d+c),
$$
which does not seem to be a constant (independent of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$) times $\det {(X)} = ad - bc$.

Comment: Yeah, even without much calculation, there is nothing stopping me from defining a linear map that maps the identity matrix to the zero matrix and some linearly independent invertible matrix e.g., the matrix with all ones on the anti-diagonal, to the identity matrix. The first condition forces the constant $c$ to be $0$, the second condition can only be true if $c \neq 0$. So I also don't think this is true.

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture is false. More generally, let us determine *all* the linear transforms $\mathscr T$ of $M_n(\Bbb C)$ such that
$$\exists c\in\Bbb C\quad\forall A\in M_n(\Bbb C)\quad\det (\mathscr{T} A)=c\,\det A.\tag{*}$$

If $c\ne0,$ let $d$ be an $n$-th root of $c.$ Then the linear transform $\mathscr S:=\frac1d\mathscr T$ is [determinant-preserving, hence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/522/linear-transformation-that-preserves-the-determinant) of the form either $A\mapsto UAV$ or $A\mapsto UA^tV$ for some regular matrices $U,V,$ and $\mathscr T$ is then of the same form.

Therefore, a necessary (and obviously sufficient) condition for $(*)$ is that either   the linear transform $\mathscr T$ is of that form, or its range is a [linear subspace of the set of singular matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47362).